# set PolicyStore in CIM instance

Tags: powershell, wmi, wbem, cim

the `Get-NetFirewallProfile` cmdlet has the option `-PolicyStore ActiveStore` which is the sum of all policies on that computer. When I run it I get the firewall profile state with GPO taken under consideration.

Alternatively I can get the CIM instance with `Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\StandardCimv2 -ClassName MSFT_NetFirewallProfile` or `Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\StandardCimv2" -Query "SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetFirewallProfile"`, BUT the GPO value are discarded.

How can I set the policy store in the `Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\StandardCimv2" -Query "SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetFirewallProfile"`?

In the end I'm going to implement the query in c++ with the [wbemcli api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify PolicyStore parameter using IWbemContext. Here are the code samples illustrating its use:

### PowerShell:

```
$CimSession = New-CimSession
$options = New-Object Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options.CimOperationOptions
$options.SetCustomOption("PolicyStore", "ActiveStore", $true)
$CimSession.EnumerateInstances("Root\StandardCimv2", "MSFT_NetFirewallProfile", $options)
```

### VB:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objSWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\StandardCimv2")

Set objCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
objCtx.Add "PolicyStore", "ActiveStore"

Set colSWbemObjectSet = objSWbemServices.InstancesOf("MSFT_NetFirewallProfile",,objCtx)
For Each objSWbemObject In colSWbemObjectSet
Wscript.Echo "Enabled: " & objSWbemObject.Enabled
Next
```